# Replace null values with just a blank

Tags: sql

I currently have a sql statement that outputs data into an excel document. However, every time there is a cell that doesn't have data, it outputs `NULL` into the cell. I was wondering if there was a way that I could replace `NULL` with just a blank space? Someone suggested using coalesce to do this, however I haven't ever had the chance to use it so I will have to do some reading on it. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: What database you are using ? Oracle? Sql Server ? MySQL ?....

Comment: Re: "I will have to do some reading on it": Wouldn't it have made more sense to do that reading *before* posting this question? :-/

Comment: My SQL and I have done some reading and it looks like it may work, but I would like to weigh out my options. For example, someone might have a better idea of just avoiding a coalesce in this situation and just use something else

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is the cause for "avoiding COALESCE()" ? Except for its ugly name, it still is a standard function (which IFNULL() et.al. are not)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your select you can put an IsNull/IfNull round the column.  Not particularly efficient but does what you want.

MS SQL

```
Select IsNull(ColName, '') As ColName From TableName
```

MySQL

```
Select IfNull(ColName, '') As ColName From TableName
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace null in case when I don't know field name? When I do select * from table?

Answer (score 9):

IFNULL is an Oracle extension (adopted by many other platforms). The "standard" SQL function is coalesce():

```
SELECT COALESCE(columnName, ' ') AS ColumnName
FROM tableName;
```

Comment: This is old, but I'd like to point out your code is inserting a space character into ever "empty" cell, which is very different from an empty string (and, in turn, is quite different from a null).

Comment: @DevinLamothe It is odd, but the Question wanted `just a blank space`. I would prefer an empty string, too.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SQL

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET COLUMN_NAME = ''
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
```

**NOTE:** this will **SET**, not select the result in your TABLE

Answer (score 0):

MySQL

```
select IFNULL(columnName, '') from tableName
```

IFNULL(expr1,expr2)

If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT teacher.name, IfNull(dept.name, '') as Dept
 FROM teacher left outer JOIN dept
           ON teacher.dept=dept.id
```