# How to convert date, but return nothing if Null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a datetime field that is store in the database looking like this: 2016-06-30 00:00:00.000

I am being asked to convert that format to dd/mm/yyyy

I can do this with 
 `Convert(varchar,PRICE_TAB.F137,103) as 'SalesPriceStartDateGood',`

This column contains NULLS though, and where it contains NULLS I want to return nothing. This is being exported to CSV so I want it to come across as ,, for that spot in the file.

How do I write the query to say convert to this format, unless null, then give me nothing?

Comment: When exporting ,cant you keep "is not null" clause

Comment: How are you exporting to CSV.

Comment: Do you know about the ISNULL() or COALESCE() functions in SQL?

Comment: @TheGameiswar - That doesn't mean he dont want entire row

Comment: @Prdp: thanks for the info

Comment: `Coalesce(Convert(varchar,PRICE_TAB.F137,103),'')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace null values with just a blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394545/replace-null-values-with-just-a-blank)

Comment: I updated my answer so it returns an empty string when the datetime field is null

Comment: I am using ISNULL on other fields but I don't understand the syntax when also using convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it without coalesce and the result seems like what you want :

```
declare @test1 datetime = getdate()
declare @test2 datetime = null

select convert(varchar, @test1, 103) as test1, 
       convert(varchar, @test2, 103) as test2
```

this returns
28/06/2016 null

if you need an empty string than just do this

```
select convert(varchar, @test1, 103) as test1, 
       isnull(convert(varchar, @test2, 103), '') as test2
```

this returns
28/06/2016 ''

for your table it will be this :

```
isnull(Convert(varchar,PRICE_TAB.F137,103), '') as SalesPriceStartDateGood'
```

Comment: why the downvote ? In my opion the answer is correct

Comment: I don't understand how this works. How do the variables refer to the column I'm pulling?

Comment: I edited my answer look at the last line this should match with your table and field names

Comment: if it works you could upvote me and maybe accept the answer

Comment: Guido, both of your answers worked by the way.
isnull(Convert(varchar,PRICE_TAB.F137,103), '') as SalesPriceStartDateGood'  
and 
Coalesce(Convert(varchar,PRICE_TAB.F137,103),'')

Comment: Thank you,I am glad I could be helpful

Answer (score -1):

One of the options...

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN PRICE_TAB.F137 IS NOT NULL
           THEN CONVERT( VARCHAR, '2016-06-30')
       END AS 'SalesPriceStartDateGood';
```

Comment: this will again return Null values